# target_link_directories for imported targets

Tags: cmake

In my project I am using `MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_FINAL` for an external library for a custom configuration `FINAL`. Is there some working example of how to set the `target_link_directories` for an imported target for the custom configuration `FINAL` using cmake.

So here are the steps :

1. The external library is boost-1.67.0 which I am installing using the following commands for Debug and Release respectively:

```
.\bootstrap.bat
```

```
.\b2 install --prefix=C:\Dev\third-party\vs2017\boost-1.67.0\Debug toolset=msvc-14.1 address-model=64 link=static -j8 variant=debug
```

```
.\b2 install --prefix=C:\Dev\third-party\vs2017\boost-1.67.0\Release toolset=msvc-14.1 address-model=64 link=static -j8 variant=release
```

2. Here is the example project with following structure

```
boost-example/
 |
 +-- main.cpp
 |    
 +-- CMakeLists.txt
 | 
 |    
 +-- CMake/
 |  |  
 |  +-- AddConfiguration.cmake
 |  +-- mpIncludeBoost.cmake
 |  +-- mpSetupMSVCRuntime.cmake
 |  +-- SetupConfigurations.cmake
```

The files are found in this gitlab project: https://gitlab.com/sunayanag/boost-example.

For the sln file generated note that in Visual Studio in the `Linker` section in `Additional Library Directories` I get `C:/Dev/third-party/boost-1_67_0/install/lib/$(Configuration)` which evaluates to `C:/Dev/third-party/boost-1_67_0/install/lib/Final` but this directory does not exist since Final is not a valid configuration of boost, it should be `C:/Dev/third-party/boost-1_67_0/install/lib/Release` instead.

I was thinking a way of getting around this would be to use `target_link_directories` but how do I use this with cmake generator expressions in this case.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure your question is clear. The `MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_<CONFIG>` property is used to *map* the configuration(s) of an external library to a configuration in your project. Is the `CFG` configuration part of your external library? Or your current project? Can you provide an example for how you are importing the external library, to better illustrate the issue?

Comment: @squareskittles please find the updated information.

Comment: The information you provided is helpful, but it is still unclear what is going wrong. Specifically, where is your call using the `MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_*` variable? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as *text* in your question post, or at least include the relevant sections of code.